# PHP how to add a style to HTML in a table

Tags: php, html-table

I want to be able to style this table:

With a dark background, the text returned is unreadable:

```
 <?php
    echo "
        <table border = '1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Client ID</th>

    </tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$clientID. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

The PHP is working.  But how do I change the color of the text in the table?

**Found a solution**

I found a simple solution to what was needed.   Use the `bgcolor = '#fff'`, this fixed the issue.

```
 <?php
    echo "
        <table border = '1'>
            *bgcolor='#fff'*
        <tr>
        <th>Client ID</th>

    </tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$clientID. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to learn CSS then, check out the [Tizag CSS Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic rundown of how to implement styles onto your page:

**HTML HEAD**

```
<head>
    <!-- example css -->
    <style type="text/css">
        table.mytable {
            border: 1px solid #FF0000;
        }
        table.mytable > thead > tr > th {
            font-size: 2em;
        }
        table.mytable > tbody > tr > td {
            color: #999;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- or below: include a css file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/my/css/file.css">
</head>
```

**Your Table** (see my changes to the DOM)

```
<table class="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Client ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- notice how I include php without echoing the whole table -->
                <?php echo $clientID; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Learn CSS**

Check out [this website](http://w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp) for a good tutorial and reference to follow for adding css properties to your page.

Comment: [w3schools is not a good resource](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: @moonwave99 Wow. Consider me enlightened. Ive always used it for a quick reference.

Comment: That should do it, thanks. Already learning CSS, but the naming of tables was causing me issues. The thread tag is new to me so will be reading up on that. Thanks for the speedy response.

Answer (score 0):

try using Bootstrap, just download it and put the files in the correct folders, put ths css files in your css folder, the js files in your javascript folder and the same thing with images, finally in your code just add classes like this:

```
<?php
echo "
    <table class='table table-striped' >
    <tr>
    <th>Client ID</th>

</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$clientID. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

take a look here for more information: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables